# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn' has no attribute 'rnn'

Tags: tensorflow

I am following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/rnn-tensorflow-python-machine-learning-tutorial/) on Recurrent Neural Networks.

This is the imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import core_rnn_cell
```

This is code for input processing:

```
x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, 0)

lstm_cell = core_rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I am getting the following error for the `outputs, states`:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn' has no attribute 'rnn'
```

TensorFlow was updated recently, so what should be the new code for the offending line

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For people using the newer version of tensorflow, add this to the code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn 


lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size) 
outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

instead of

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell 
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True) 
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

PS: @BrendanA suggested that `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` be used instead of `rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`

Comment: This is hard to follow, would you please indicate which versions of TensorFlow you are referring to. Is the top 1.1 and the bottom is 0.12?

Comment: The code at the top is for 1.1 and the bottom is 0.12

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: As of v.1.11 `rnn.BasicLSTMCell` has been deprecated in favor of `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell`. See [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.11/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn).

Comment: Thanks @BrendanA. for pointing it out. I will update the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @suku

I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn'`

To solve:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn
```

replaced by:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
```

---

and in my code I had used `core_rnn.static_rnn`:

```
 outputs,_ = core_rnn.static_rnn(cell, input_list, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I got the this error:

`NameError: name 'core_rnn' is not defined`

This is solved by replacing the line by:

```
outputs,_ = rnn.static_rnn(cell, input_list, dtype=tf.float32)
```

python: 3.6 64bit
rensorflow:1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Use static_rnn method instead of rnn.

```
 outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

instead of:

```
 outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```